# Making A Window With C

Tags: c

I have been using the below code to make a simple window within C.  When Compiling a get the error C4133, ive brought up the error in visual online but unable to resolve. (Apologies this is badly written)

```
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{
WNDCLASSEX wc;
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;

//Step 1: Registering the Window Class
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

// Step 2: Creating the Window
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    g_szClassName,
    "The title of my window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

// Step 3: The Message Loop
while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
return Msg.wParam;
```

}

Comment: First off you should mark your question as `Windows`, and secondly, what is the error? You haven't provided it anywhere (apart from its code, which is not very useful). The code compiles fine for me (Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: Also, all errors/warnings have a line number. You should indicate which line has the error.

Comment: Warning C4133 '=': incompatible types - from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: You have our project settings set to UNICODE and yet you are using normal strings.  You should set your literal strings to L"..." instead of "..."

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in Visual Studio 2015, in case the character set is "not set" or "multi byte" everything compiles without any errors or warnings.
Also the window is shown if I execute the exe.
"Unicode fails" because ansi strings are used.

So I suppose you need to change to ansi "not set" for the used character set.

Otherwise additional information for the error are necessary (line etc) compiler settings VStudio version?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has been explained in the answer from Bjoern. Actually the usage of the old ascii version of winapi is becoming rare, the preference is for unicode (widechar) version code.
Anyway there is a way to write code independent from the ansi/widechar version using the `_T()` macro and the generic tchar macros.
Try you emended code with ascii and unicode compilations:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

TCHAR g_szClassName[] = _T("myWindowClass");

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

//Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Registration Failed!"), _T("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

// Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, g_szClassName, _T("The title of my window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Creation Failed!"), _T("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

// Step 3: The Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;

}
```